# Server 2008 Unable to load user profile

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, login, windows-registry

So I have a RDS deployment on a virtualized Server 2008 install.  Yesterday I ran into an error where users would get the message

> "The user profile service failed the logon - User profile service could not be loaded"

At the same time when users get this message I was seeing 3 failures in the event viewer:

> Windows unable to load the registry. This problem is often caused by >insufficient memory or insufficient rights
> DETAIL- Insufficient system resources exist to complete the requested service >for C:\Users\userx\ntuser.dat
>
> Windows cannot load the locally stored profile.  Possible causes of this error >include insufficient security rights or a corrupt profile.
> DETAIL- Insufficient system resources exist to complete the requested service
>
> Widows cannot log you on because your profile cannot be loaded.  check that you >are connected to the network, and that your network is functioning properly
> DETAIL- Unspecified Error

At the moment roughly 8 users can be logged in at once, if one user logs off another user is able to take their place, but anything past the 8 users will give this error message again.  I've seen several thread on this topic and have tried a few things to try to resolve the issue, but non have worked.  Most recently I found there is a bug with the print spooler on Server 2008 causing the registry hive at "HKEY_USERS.DEFAULT\Printers\DevModes2"to expand and cause this issue.  When i try to Open that hive my entire system freezes and needs to be rebooted so I think it may be safe to say this expansion has happened. While trying to analyze and compress my registry I keep getting a new error message though simple saying

> insufficient resources exist to complete the requested service

I'm stuck now and don't know where to go from here.  This server is typically accessed by roughly 50 concurrent users daily so we need to find a solution to allow more than 8 users to log in at once.

Any help is really appreciated!

Comment: What is the size of %systemroot%\system32\config\default?

Comment: Its 1.02 gb or to be more specific 1,076,992KB

Comment: Get all the users off of the server, logon to the console of the server and then proceed to edit the registry. How much RAM is in this server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't bother with trying to open the key with regedit if it is that large.  Try deleting the offending key while offline with the command prompt:

```
REG DELETE HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Printers\DevModes2 /f 
REG ADD HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Printers\DevModes2
```

Then perform the offline registry compression of the Default hive per:

How to Compress "Bloated" Registry Hives
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2498915

Comment: This seems to have solved my issue!  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can actually edit the registry offline

To do so you can either :

- attach the faulting server virtual disk to another server on which you will run regedit
- or boot it in recovery mode and from the recovery console command prompt type "start regedit"

Once regedit is open, clik on the "HKEY_USERS" to select it, then in menu "File" select "load hive", navigate to C:\Windows\system32\config directory and select "DEFAULT".

Give it whatever name you want.

Correct the registry errors then in the "file" menu, unload the hive (it's important since it is what will write back the file on the disk).

Of course as always, make a backup of the file before modifying it...

Comment: From the recovery console I tried this and got all the way up to loading the hive before I got an error.  I went to load the hive, selected the DEFAULT file and gave it a key name but then was presented with an error message saying "Cannot Load X:\Windows\System32\config\DEFAULT : The Process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process"